# Brute Force or Calculate Serial RS232 Checksums

Tags: serial-port, checksum, crc

I'm communicating with a control panel via a bootloader and I have some serial data captured. It looks to be in a modified API format with each command preceded and ended with `7E`.

I can't seem to determine how the CRC is being calculated. Based on the API format, the 1st byte frames the message, the second and third bytes are the length of the message, the fourth byte looks to be the type of command. The next few bytes are the data address or what is being requested, the third to last byte and second to last byte look to be the Checksum and the last byte contains `7E` to close the frame.

I found some other posts that were answered with a docklight script that brute-forced the CRC using some standard CRC types, but the scripts don't work for my data.

Some of the sample messages below

Queries to Bootloader:

```
7e  07  00  0d  24  12  7f  00  40  00  e1  3b  7e
7e  07  00  1a  00  d0  3e  00  70  00  ad  3d  7e
7e  01  00  1f  0e  18  7e
7e  07  0   0d  34  00  7f  00  04  00  9f  fa  7e
7e  0a  00  18  00  00  00  00  00  00  80  7b  00  83  c0  7e
```

Responses from bootloader (Random, these are not responses based on the above queries)

```
7e 41 00 85 0b 03 03 03 04 00 03 03 00 03 00 00 07 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 45 9e 7e

7e 05 00 85 da 8c 66 01 e3 ce 7e
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit November 2, 2021**

Some additional information below.

```
 7e 0a 00 18 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 01 00 c6 47 7e   ~.....€......ÆG~ 
 7e 0a 00 18 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 7b 00 83 c0 7e   ~.........€{.ƒÀ~ 

These Commands appear to use
Polynomial: 1021
Initial Value: 2241
Final Xor: 0
Refin = True
RefOut= True
CRC Data Length = 12 Bytes


7e 07 00 0d 00 6a 4e 00 00 08 99 7b 7e            ~....jN...™{~    
7e 07 00 0d 00 72 4e 00 90 00 ec 00 7e            ~....rN..ì.~    
7e 07 00 0d 34 00 7f 00 04 00 9f fa 7e            ~...4....Ÿú~    
7e 07 00 0d 24 12 7f 00 40 00 e1 3b 7e            ~...$..@.á;~    
7e 07 00 1a 00 d0 3e 00 70 00 ad 3d 7e            ~....Ð>.p.­=~    
7e 07 00 0d 00 5a 4e 00 00 08 48 af 7e            ~....ZN...H¯~    
7e 07 00 0d 00 62 4e 00 00 08 b9 21 7e            ~....bN...¹!~    

These Commands appear to use
Polynomial: 1021
Initial Value: 0daa
Final Xor: 0
Refin = True
RefOut= True
CRC Data Length = 9 Bytes
  
7e 02 00 14 00 b6 fd 7e   ~....¶ý~ 
7e 02 00 14 01 3f ec 7e   ~....?ì~ 
7e 02 00 14 02 a4 de 7e   ~....¤Þ~ 
7e 02 00 14 03 2d cf 7e   ~....-Ï~ 
7e 02 00 14 04 92 bb 7e   ~....’»~ 
7e 02 00 14 05 1b aa 7e   ~.....ª~ 
7e 02 00 14 06 80 98 7e   ~....€˜~ 
7e 02 00 14 07 09 89 7e   ~.....‰~ 
7e 02 00 14 08 fe 71 7e   ~....þq~ 
7e 02 00 14 09 77 60 7e   ~....w`~ 
7e 02 00 14 0a ec 52 7e   ~....ìR~ 
7e 02 00 14 0b 65 43 7e   ~....eC~ 
7e 02 00 14 0c da 37 7e   ~....Ú7~ 
7e 02 00 14 0d 53 26 7e   ~....S&~ 
7e 02 00 14 0e c8 14 7e   ~....È.~ 
7e 02 00 14 0f 41 05 7e   ~....A.~ 
7e 02 00 14 10 37 ed 7e   ~....7í~ 
7e 02 00 14 11 be fc 7e   ~....¾ü~ 
7e 02 00 14 12 25 ce 7e   ~....%Î~ 
7e 02 00 14 13 ac df 7e   ~....¬ß~ 
7e 02 00 14 14 13 ab 7e   ~.....«~ 
7e 02 00 14 15 9a ba 7e   ~....šº~ 

These Commands appear to use
Polynomial: 1021
Initial Value: 90F8
Final Xor: 0
CRC Data Length = 4 Bytes
```

So, the Initial Value being used to calculate the CRC is changing based on the message length excluding the framing byte 7e and start and finish, and the 2 CRC Bytes.

I guess I could try to send some requests that result in different message lengths and calculate the CRCs using that method up to whatever message size I feel that I am going to require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to not include the first two bytes (the length) in the CRC calculation. You will then find that the initial value is `0xffff`, and the final exclusive-or is `0xffff`.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks, couldn't see the forest through the trees. Trying to determine too many different components of the message! Thank you so much for the help!